# Arrays, multi-dimensional and jagged...in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

C# through ASP.Net 2.0.

In a datatable I have two columns of IDs, attributeId and productAttributeID.

I want to loop through this table and 'group' them in such a way that productAttributeIds have one or more attributeIds associated with them.

For example, in pseudo-code this is what I'm doing

```
For each datarow in myDatatable.rows

Insert into myarray at index(productattributeId) - corresponding attributeId

end foreach
```

So this will loop and each time the same productAttributeId is present, the attributeId will be added to the array corresponding.

Obviously this won't work as arrays need to be size declared etc.

I've tried multi-dimensional arrays, jagged arrays, arraylists, lists of arraylists all to no avail, my code is failing yet I know in theory what I want to do.

Comment: Does it have to be an array? Why not simply use e.g. a Stack?

Comment: @Martin: While I agree that an array probably isn't the right approach, I fail to see how a Stack helps.

Comment: You're right, my approach was just a short sketch of thoughts: scaryjones said that `arrays need to be size declared`, so I thought about some simple dynamically allocatable list, although List.Add() would have been sufficient. A complete answer would have contained a List of Lists (or a Dictionary, as mentioned below).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would, personally, use a `Dictionary<int, List<int>>`:

```
foreach(var row in data)
{
    // Get your data...
    int attributeId = GetAttributeId();
    int productAttributeId = GetProductAttributeId();

    List<int> attributes;
    if(!dictionary.TryGetValue(productAttributeId, out attributes)
    {
       attributes = new List<int>();
       dictionary[productAttributeId] = attributes;
    }
    attributes.Add(attributeId);
}
```

You can then easily get all of the product attributes for an attribute:

```
List<int> attributeIds = dictionary[productAttributeId];
```

Comment: @Reed: Out of interest, if you had LINQ available to you would you still use this approach, or would you use a lookup as per my answer?

Comment: @Jon: Nope - I'd use LINQ (either .ToLookup or .ToDictionary, depending on how I planned to use it in the future).  But the OP mentioned .NET 2.0, and I don't usually post something recommending a 3rd party lib if there's a way to handle it directly in the framework...

Comment: I voted up your answer - because I like it "better" - but it does require LINQBridge, which is why I hadn't suggested something similar.

Comment: @Reed - You sir, are a genius and a scholar. This has been wrecking my head for days and you solved it so quickly. Brilliant. I'm only beginning to use Stackoverflow properly so am not sure how to set your answer as the one I've used, have ticked the green arrow. Many thanks to the others who replied as well, this site is so helpful.

Comment: @scaryjones: Welcome to StackOverflow - (and yes, ticking the green arrow is the appropriate thing to do - that says this was the answer that helped you ;) )

Comment: Ok, well have set it as the answer. The only downside to asking questions here is being shown very quickly, and by multiple people, how little you actually know! But in a good way.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you don't really want an array at all - you want a dictionary with multiple values per entry. If you can use LINQ, that's exactly what `ToLookup` does for you. Something like:

```
var lookup = dataTable.AsEnumerable()
                      .ToLookup(row => row.Field<int>("ProductAttributeId"),
                                row => row.Field<int>("AttributesId"));
```

You can then do things like:

```
foreach (int attributeId in lookup[5])
{
   ...
}
```

Of course, you have to have .NET 3.5 for this, or you could use [LINQBridge](http://linqbridge.googlecode.com/) if you're using .NET 2.0.

Comment: I wish I could use LINQ....I'll investigate this LinqBridge you speak of though, sounds interesting.